# WPF Hide on Close?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

How do i do this in wpf

VB.NET

```
   Private Sub FrmSettings_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        e.Cancel = (e.CloseReason = Forms.CloseReason.UserClosing)
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

c#

```
private void FrmSettings_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = (e.CloseReason == Forms.CloseReason.UserClosing);
    this.Hide();
}
```

as wpf's Close event just gives me e.Cancel and no closereason :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not an equivalent in the default implementation of WPF.  You can use a windows hook to get the reason though.

The following post details how to do this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/549a4bbb-e77b-4c5a-b724-07996774c60a/

Comment: How ugly that there is nothing built in :(

Answer (score 7):

I would like to thank Bob King for his hint and make an addition to his code as C# WPF. It works for me. My application is a tray icon by type. In a WPF XAML form code behind:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInitialized(e);

    Application.Current.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
}

private bool m_isExplicitClose = false;// Indicate if it is an explicit form close request from the user.

protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)

{

    base.OnClosing(e);

    if (m_isExplicitClose == false)//NOT a user close request? ... then hide
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }

}

private void OnTaskBarMenuItemExitClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

{            
    m_isExplicitClose = true;//Set this to unclock the Minimize on close 

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: This way it will crash when closed through task manager or at windows logoff

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand what the WinForms approach solves.

Isn't it better to always do this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnClosing(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
    e.Cancel = True
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

And then set this in your Application?

```
Application.Current.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose
```

This way, whenever your child windows close, you keep them around for faster display later, but your app still shutsdown when the main window closes (i.e. Exit, Shutdown, etc).

Comment: This way it will not close through task manager or at windows logoff. Also in this case you can't save application data on exit.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you're saying @Poma... you can override the Applications OnExit method to handle saving data on exit, etc.

Comment: If I shutdown windows Applications OnExit method will never be called because cancelling close event will prevent application from closing. Eventually windows will just kill this process.

Comment: That's definitely not true at all. You have some additional changes outside of this base case that are causing your app to not exit cleanly. Are you marking a main window correctly? Is your main window not visible at shutdown. My solution works in our application reliable and cleanly.